# Remove start job for disc not in use

Tags: startup, fstab, manjaro

I am very new to Linux and it seems that i have created an bad issue. I wanted to install another OS on a disc already in use by my Linux Manjaro. I did format the disc and installed the os. I forgot to remove it from the fstab file, so every time i boot i tries to start the device that does no longer exist. More specifically "A start job is running for ....."  I cannot continue and i dont know how to remove the start job for the device.

All help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can fix this by entering into single user mode Please follow this https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-boot-manjaro-into-text-mode-text-only-console-mode-and-troubleshoot-at-bootup-2018-tutorial/45638

Comment: I read the thread and are not sure if this helps me. I can get to emergency mode and type in a prompt there, but nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: get into the emergency mode.

Step 2: update your fstab file (typically using `nano`) with the correct parameters.

Step 3: restart your computer.

Comment: Thank you. Worked flawlessly.